# React Router v6 Hashrouter does not use top level "not found" route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, url-routing

In a project I'm using the react router v6 hashrouter for in page navigation. My routes are build like the following setup:

```
<Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Layout/>}>
        <Route index element={<StartPage/>}/>
        <Route path="topcams" element={<TopCams/>}/>
        <Route path="videostation" element={<Videos/>}/>
        <Route path="categories" element={<Categories/>}/>
        <Route path="profile/:id" element={<Profile/>}/>
        <Route path="*" element={<StartPage/>} />
    </Route>
</Routes>
```

Which works fine. When the url is something like https://www.example.com#/random it drops into the Startpage and all is well. But when the hash is missing the starting slash (i.e. https://www.example.com#random) it logs out to the console 'No routes matched location "random"' and does not display anything.

Well, okay, so I tried this:

```
<Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Layout/>}>
        <Route index element={<StartPage/>}/>
        <Route path="topcams" element={<TopCams/>}/>
        <Route path="videostation" element={<Videos/>}/>
        <Route path="categories" element={<Categories/>}/>
        <Route path="profile/:id" element={<Profile/>}/>
        <Route path="*" element={<StartPage/>} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="*" element={<StartPage/>} />
</Routes>
```

But that does not work, it still logs the same message and does not display anything. So I tried moving the catch-all up, but it makes no difference. I seem to be unable to catch-all a hash that doesn't start with a slash. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have used same code in codesandbox.io  and it is working fine.

Comment: I am also unable to reproduce the issue in a running codesandbox.